# Is the way sehr pronounced correct?

Tags: pronunciation

My German A1 teacher pronounce `sehr` as /zehr/ pronounced in English.
Is this correct? Online German dictionary has /ze:ɐ̯/ as IPA. I just want to know
is his pronunciation as a correct alternative?

Comment: Actually most people would pronounce it /ze:ɐ̯/ I think.

Comment: */zehr/ pronounced in English* – Is */zehr/* supposed to be IPA or some weird English phonetic description? If the former, it’s unpronouncable; if the latter, what do you actually want to state (can you translate this to proper IPA)?

Comment: Voting to close as unclear until you clarify what kind of pronunciation you’re trying to replicate (phonemic, phonetic or ‘like in English’; they require slashes, square brackets or just general italics).

Comment: Also to answer @Jan's comment to my question, I'm assuming the OP used https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling when he wrote /zehr/

Comment: @Raketenolli Maybe. But the tables listed in the [relevant article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pronunciation_respelling_for_English) show only one way of pronouncing *eh* namely [ɛ]. That is a wrong (but understood) pronunciation; it could be associated with a Russian accent. However, this usage of *eh* is not consistent across respelling variants and it could also be meant to describe the sequence of sounds [ɛh]. Which means we still don’t have clarity.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with /zehr/ is that it tries to imitate the proper German pronunciation of *sehr* by something that resembles an English word. The /h/ for example is not an indicator of a certain sound by itself, it only serves to tell the speaker that the *e* is a long one. The /r/ also indicates that the word should be pronounces somewhat like *wear* or *tear* (as in tearing apart), but IMHO also results in an audible [r] at the end of the word -- it shouldn't be there in the proper German pronunciation, and it will also reinforce a typical American English accent.

So even though an American-sounding /zehr/ would very likely be easily understood, the IPA provides the correct pronunciation.

Comment: /zehr/ (although that would most likely be rendered /zehər/) sounds more like *Seher* to me than *sehr* — although neither include a /h/ sound. If you have figured out OP’s cryptic pronunciation guide, would you please share it with us by editing the question accordingly?